# Access values inside array using pointers

Tags: arrays, go, pointers

I've noticed in golang that we can use a pointer to an array as follows:

```
arr := [3]int{1, 2, 3}
var ptr *[3]int = &arr
```

To get value stored at an index n we can do `(*ptr)[n]`, but why does `ptr[n]` also fetch me the value, Shouldn't it output some random address ?

**Context**

In C++, this is the observed behaviour

```
int (*ptr)[5];
int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};

ptr = &arr;
cout <<"ptr[1] = " << ptr[1] <<endl; //Outputs an address (base address of array + 20bytes)
cout << "(*ptr)[1] = " << (*ptr)[1]<< endl; //Outputs 2
```

Comment: In C++ there is [array-to-pointer decay](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array) (implicit conversion from values of array type to values of pointer type), but no the same conversion in Go.

Comment: Go deliberately omits all the horrible things you can do to yourself with pointers in C and C++. The result is that you can't accidentally shoot yourself in the foot (C), or accidentally create numerous instances of yourself and shoot all of them in the foot (C++). See also https://www-users.cs.york.ac.uk/susan/joke/foot.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For `a` of [pointer](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Pointer_types) to array
> type:
>
> - `a[x]` is shorthand for `(*a)[x]`

See language spec: [Index Expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Index_expressions).